# Execution Order of Thread in Java Main Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a demo Spring boot project, and will create a Thread Pool when starts application.

In Main Thread, if there are:

1. `Task A`: with lots of API call, and will be submitted to Thread Pool
2. `Task B`: only a database query, and will not be submitted to Thread Pool

I have below questions:

1. Will `Task B` execute early then `Task A` if following below code approach?
2. Can `Task B` wait until `Task A` have finished and then execute? If can, how to achieve?
3. Assume if there are no idle Worker Threads to handle `Task A`, what will happen ? Will the Main Thread skip `Task A` and continue to execute `Task B` first?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        // Task A submitting to Thread Pool
        executor.submit(() -> 
           // process 1: fetch API
           // process 2: call Database 
           // process 3: fetch API
           // process 4: call Database 
        );

        // Task B not submitting to Thread Pool
        db.query(xxx);

}
```

Comment: `executor.submit` returns a Future.  Use Future::get

Comment: How about if `Task A` do not return anything, can `Task B` execute after `Task A` have finished?

Comment: Why are you using `ExecutorService` ?  Why not just use Thread::join?

Comment: @auntR you can just make it return some placeholder value like null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not important if any of the tasks return anything. When things run in parallel threads then they run in parallel until one of them finished or you explicitly wait for one in the other.

What does run in parallel actually mean? Depends. If the machine where code runs on has multiple CPU cores available then it can actually run in parallel (one core handles one thread), if not then it may run in any random way. Something like "do one atomic operation in thread A, then two in thread B and then again one in thread A" may be one option, but it's nothing you can control. If you wan't to make sure things run in some certain order then either use `Future.get()`, `Thread.join()` or Javas completable future framework.